# How to write settings in Grafana-zabbix dashboard

Tags: grafana, zabbix

I'm using zabbix and It was easy to setup Grafana-zabbix by intergrating plugin.
However I am totally new to Grafana and don't know what to write settings.

Group is Zabbix host group?
Host is hostname in zabbix settings?
I complete have no idea how to write "Item".

I'm monitoring PostgreSQL with pg_monz template.
I'm hoping to use Grafana because this visualizing is flesible.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using this plugin: https://grafana.com/plugins/alexanderzobnin-zabbix-app ?

First of all, you need to setup the data source connection from Grafana to Zabbix (Datasources -> Add data source).

You can create a "read all" account on Zabbix for this purpose.
Use the "Save and Test" button to check the configuration and the communication between Zabbix and Grafana.

The grafana-zabbix matching is straightforward:

- Group : Zabbix Hostgroup
- Host : Host
- Application : Zabbix item's application, as defined in the template
- Item: the item itself

Try to insert by hand an host group, then move to the Host input field: the host list should autocomplete.
The same goes for application and items.

I strongly suggest you to read the Getting Started guide (http://docs.grafana-zabbix.org/guides/gettingstarted/) and the Templating Guide (http://docs.grafana-zabbix.org/guides/templating/)

Comment: Thank I did not find intro docs. I already connect grafana to zabbix by using plugin that you told me.  I was tottaly lost in writing query settings at the pic I showed. Seems straightforward.  Thanks!!

Comment: I just set the user with insufficient privileges. As you said, autocomplete works!

Comment: Glad to help! In my opinion, the real power of the Zabbix-Grafana plugin lies in the Templating plus Regexp function: read the documentation and experiment, you'll get awesome dashboards in no time.
Also, if the answer solved you issue, please don't forget to mark it as accepted